# Creating a list of M columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
cleanData = cleanData.sort_values("Name")
        FinalGrade =computeFinalGrades(cleanData)
        studentList = cleanData["Studentid"].tolist()
        nameList = cleanData["Name"].tolist()
        gradelist1 = cleanData["Assignment1"].tolist()
        gradelist2 = cleanData["Assignment2"].tolist()
        gradelist3 = cleanData["Assignment3"].tolist()

        for i in range(len(studentList)):
            print(studentList[i], "  ", nameList[i], ":  ",gradelist1[i], ", ", gradelist2[i], ", ", gradelist3[i], ", ",  FinalGrade[i])
```

It gives me this ouput:

```
You have chosen to the show grade list for your file's data.
StudentID  Name                                    Final grade
s126519    Alberte Olsen :   2.0 ,  12.0 ,  0.0 ,  7.0
s123333    Alexander Hansen :   7.0 ,  12.0 ,  nan ,  12.0
s123789    Bettina Petersen :   12.0 ,  10.0 ,  10.0 ,  12.0
s128348    Ewan McGregor :   12.0 ,  nan ,  nan ,  12.0
s126734    Jepser Jespersen :   nan ,  nan ,  nan ,  -3.0
s121042    Josephine Brandt :   12.0 ,  12.0 ,  nan ,  12.0
s123235    Katinka Damgaard :   7.0 ,  7.0 ,  7.0 ,  7.0
s127110    Lise Christiansen :   -3.0 ,  -3.0 ,  -3.0 ,  -3.0
s123579    Marie Hansen :   10.0 ,  12.0 ,  nan ,  12.0
s123456    Michael Andersen :   7.0 ,  7.0 ,  4.0 ,  7.0
s124444    Nanna Nygaard :   10.0 ,  4.0 ,  4.0 ,  7.0
s121234    Natalie Sørensen :   4.0 ,  10.0 ,  nan ,  10.0
s128190    Sara Poulsen :   12.0 ,  12.0 ,  12.0 ,  12.0
s127698    Sebastian Bruun :   7.0 ,  10.0 ,  10.0 ,  10.0
s123468    Thomas Nielsen :   -3.0 ,  7.0 ,  2.0 ,  -3.0
```

It lists the StudentID, Name, grades for three assignments and the final grade. But how do i programme it so it is able to handle M amount of assignments so i don't have to write gradelist5000 if there is 5000 assignments? And also how do I align the numbers so it looks prettier?

Comment: *so i don't have to write gradelist5000 if there is 5000 assignments?* I don't see that written anywhere in the code

Comment: No it was a hypothetical. Right now there are only three assignments but my code has to be able to handle any number of assignments

Comment: Post the relevant code please, this isn't crystal enough to solve what you're asking.

Comment: Use Array-of-Arrays data structure for `gradelist`, i.e. `gradelist[N]` is the list of data for "Assignment N"?

Comment: The list of data contains studentID, Name, and grades for M amount of assignments. From the grades for M amount of assignments we calculate a final grade in the function computeFinalGrades(cleanData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the task you've specified, there's no need to iterate rows explicitly. Nor is there a need to convert each series to a list. Just specify columns and use `print`.

First add `FinalGrade` as a series to your dataframe. Then select an arbitrary number of `'Assignment'` columns via sequence unpacking (`*` operator):

```
cleanData['FinalGrade'] = computeFinalGrades(cleanData)
assignment_cols = [f'Assignment{i}' for i in range(1, 501)]
print(cleanData[['Studentid', 'Name', *assignment_cols, 'FinalGrade']])
```

Comment: That worked for the most part. However the final grade comes from computeFinalGrades(cleanData) and is therefore an array so it won't print it. Anyway to get around that?

Comment: If it's an array consistent with the dataframe index, you can use the first line: `cleanData['FinalGrade'] = computeFinalGrades(cleanData)`. If values are not aligned, you'll need to adjust your function to align. If you get stuck here, this is likely another question.

Comment: It is not. It is a function we made so the ouput is [ 7. 12. 12. 12. -3. 12.  7. -3. 12.  7.  7. 10. 12. 10. -3.]

Comment: @asdfjkl, OK, I'm afraid that's another problem. You need to work out how you can provide an array / series aligned with your dataframe. If you're stuck after a few attempts, feel free to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and show your attempts.